# Receiving IP Packets from a raw socket

Tags: python, ip, raw-sockets

I have the following code to get me all the IP packets that are sent to my machine:

```
import socket

rs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    while True:
        print rs.recvfrom(65565)
```

I get multiple lines of something like this printed out to my console

```
('E \x004tC\x00\x007\x06\x99\x97\xd8:\xdb\xee\xc0\xa8\x00\xf8\x01\xbb\xa3\xb6\xb9\x1cmavT\x14\xbd\x80\x10\x01^\xa6W\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n,k\xe0*\x01+\xf4{', ('216.58.219.238', 0))
```

I'm gussing this is a IP packet but Im not sure how to interpret this data received. I want to know how to dissect this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/index.html) to dissect the packet, below is dissected IP packet for your example data:

```
>>> b = 'E\x004tC\x00\x007\x06\x99\x97\xd8:\xdb\xee\xc0\xa8\x00\xf8\x01\xbb\xa3\xb6\xb9\x1cmavT\x14\xbd\x80\x10\x01^\xa6W\x00\x00\x01\x01\x08\n,k\xe0*\x01+\xf4{'
>>> c = IP(b)
>>> c.show()
###[ IP ]###
  version= 4L
  ihl= 5L
  tos= 0x20
  len= 52
  id= 29763
  flags= 
  frag= 0L
  ttl= 55
  proto= tcp
  chksum= 0x9997
  src= 216.58.219.238
  dst= 192.168.0.248
  \options\
###[ TCP ]###
     sport= https
     dport= 41910
     seq= 3105647969
     ack= 1985221821
     dataofs= 8L
     reserved= 0L
     flags= A
     window= 350
     chksum= 0xa657
     urgptr= 0
     options= [('NOP', None), ('NOP', None), ('Timestamp', (745267242, 19657851))]
```